# Sql Pivoting with Multiple Aggregate Function

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql mentioned in Image. Need the output which is  also mentioned in the image.

[Main Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft4bH.png)

[Pivot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQoRE.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes but only for one column. Not able to do pivoting for two agreegate conditions. Pls help

Comment: Pls help on the same

Comment: Is anyone here to help me out